# We need to rename highlighted tabs in Bitrix 24 self hosted due to business requirement

Tags: bitrix

We need to rename highlighted tabs in Bitrix 24 self hosted due to business requirement.

Location: CRM>Quotes
Requirement:

1. Exact steps to edit/rename fields
2. If possible, screenshot would be more helpful
3. Location of labels in Control Panel.

[image: click here]

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Host name / bitrix/admin/fileman_file_edit.php?lang=en&site=s1&path=%2Fbitrix%2Fcomponents%2Fbitrix%2Fcrm.contact.show%2Ftemplates%2F.default%2Flang%2Fen%2Ftemplate.php&full_src=Y 
 change in this file your label name and save it. your tab name is changes. I am find it through the search.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate filter tab with new custom name and then delete old ones.

[image: Hot to duplicate filter]